# Use integer values in iOS json payload in Azure Notification Hub

Tags: json, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub, payload

I have the following payload for iOS to send push notifications with Azure Notification Hub:

```
{
   "aps":{
      "alert":{
         "title":"$(titleParam)",
         "body":"$(bodyParam)"
      },
      "badge":"$(badgeParam)",
      "sound":"default"
   }
}
```

That works fine exept the badgeParam. This [must be a int value](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html) in order to work with iOS. If i remove the double quotes for badgeParam like so `"body": $(bodyParam)` the payload cannot be registered in Notification Hub (invalid character `$`).

How do i have to format the payload to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try `"badge":"#(badgeParam)"`, the '#' token is specially designed for integers and booleans.